# Do different foods restore a different amount of hunger?

Tags: legend-of-grimrock

While exploring the depths of mount Grimrock, your adventurers can find different kinds of food. Excluding their aspect, is the weight the only difference between the various foods, or do they restore a different amount of hunger as well? If the latter is true, is the amount dependant on the weight?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After performing some research, I am ready to present my findings. I've taken a relatively hungry character, and started sampling various foods to see how much each type would alleviate my hunger:

- Snail Slice:

  - Weight: 2.4kg
  - Gain: 101 pixels
- Herder Cap:

  - Weight: 1.8kg
  - Gain: 98 pixels
- Mole Jerky:

  - Weight: 1.4kg
  - Gain: 84 pixels
- Baked Maggot:

  - Weight: 1.1kg
  - Gain: 75 pixels
- Boiled Crag Beetle:

  - Weight: 0.5kg
  - Gain: 57 pixels
- Grim Cap:

  - Weight: 0.3kg
  - Gain: 57 pixels

So it would seem that as a general rule, the heavier the food, the more it reduces hunger (with the exception of the Girm Cap and the Beetle, which reduce the same amount of hunger).

Comment: I've gone ahead and updated my answer using science!

Answer (score 0):

According to the wiki, all foods restore the same amount of hunger.

"Food items have varying weights yet provide the same benefit."

[Source](http://grimrockwiki.net/wiki/Carrying_Capacity)

Comment: I think what they are saying on the wiki is while they have different weight, but other then that they all provide the same benefit (reducing hunger at various amounts).